# PHP mssql_query return null for accented characters

Tags: php, sql-server

If a field in a row contains an accented character, or any other strange character, that field become null.
I have tried `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8')` and also `mssql_query('SET NAMES utf-8')` but nothing of this works. 
Is there something that I could be missing?

I tried `mssql_fetch_row()` and `mssql_fetch_array()`, both with the same results.

Comment: Before you continue, is this a new project? If it is you should be using PDO with the mssql driver.

Comment: yes I was trying to use that library, but this project is in a shared hosting, and PDO is not installed.